# <img alt="" src="{{media url='wysiwyg/uploads/printing-shadw.jpg'}}"> not working magento

Tags: magento

I have uploaded `printing-shadw.jpg` image into uploads folder and I want to display this image in my custom view. this image is visible at back end in `WYSIWYG Editor` but not visible at front end.

When I look up this image code in firebug it shows like

`<img alt="" src="{{media url='wysiwyg/uploads/printing-shadw.jpg'}}">`

Is something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Check how you have the image specified in the editor.  For magento, the wysiwyg folder is usually inside the media folder, so it would be in the format `http://domainname/media/wysiwyg/imagename.jpg`  You shouldn't need to specify the braces anywhere in the editor for this.

Comment: I just use `insert image option` inside editor and its added itself this code. Although this code is showing images in admin panel.

Comment: I would turn the editor off using Show/Hide Editor.  Then in a browser window, see if you can display http://domainname/media/wysiwyg/uploads/printing-shadow.jpg

Comment: Then you could paste that URL into the page where you want it with the editor turned off.  I can't explain why it shows on your admin page, but not in the CMS page.  hope this helps.

Comment: thanks @sconnie for the help ! It works with full url but I think it should pick path by its syntax for making it server independent , Well still searching for solution.